# remove all the text until string occurence in a file

Tags: bash, file, unix

I have a css file with one commented line:

... css code

`/*!ENDBASE*/`

... css code

I need to remove everything before `/*!ENDBASE*/` (included) in a file and must work on minified css too (so not line based)

how I can achieve that using sed or other similar bash commands?

Comment: It's line based up until the line containing the sentinel value!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this `sed`:

```
sed -i.bak '1,/\/\*!ENDBASE\*\//d' file
```

This will delete all the lines from line #1 to the search term `/*!ENDBASE*/`

Comment: You can't delete the line containing `/*!ENDBASE*/` if there are any characters after that string on the line.

Comment: I thought by writing `(included)` OP wanted to delete this line as well.

Comment: brilliant, thank you, and yes i wanted to delete that line too, +1 for you even though I'm not allowed to vote yet

Comment: Yes you need at least 15 reps to upvote any answer on SO. You have 15 now :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this `awk`:

```
awk -v RS='/\*!ENDBASE\*/' 'BEGIN{ORS=RS} NR>1' file.css
```

Logic: split the file with `/*!ENDBASE*/` as delimiter. Print record #2 onwards.

Comment: Nice, but I'm not sure you want to set ORS.  If the sentinel appears more than once in the file, perhaps that should be treated as an error.  (ie, add `NR>2 { print "error message" > "/dev/stderr"; exit 1; }`